# Store "email" in contact info during registration - Azure AD B2C Custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've a custom policy for sign up & sign in and, in the last step, I ask the user to enter the email, where I send a verification code and verify the code (following one of the examples provided by Microsoft). However, I'd like to store, in the "contact info" the email that the person entered.

I tried multiple ways using "PersistedClaims", but it doesn't seem to work.

```
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
      </PersistedClaims>
```

I got no error when I load the policy, but when I sign up, I still don't see the email in the Contact Info inside the user's profile in Azure AD B2C.

I believe that I'm using the wrong claim, but I couldn't figure out what it the "Contact info -> Email" claim.

[image]

Please, could someone tell me which claim and how to store it?

Thank you

Comment: hi, perhaps some server logs might have something?

Answer (score 1):

Change “email” to “mail”.
Change “signInName.emailAddress” to “signInName” (if this is during sign up)

Comment: Thank you.
In the end, the way the policy has been designed, I had to add this
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="mail" />
to   <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">